# wildcard usage with xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm having problems with selecting both following tags with xpath:

```
<div class="table-row">
<div class="table-row ">
```

I tried with:

```
"//div[@class='table-row*']"
```

but this won't match any of above.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `starts-with` to match in the place of wildcard **`'*'`**

```
//div[starts-with(@class, 'table-row')]
```

Comment: also... //div[contains(@class, 'table-row')]

Comment: @stav: `contains` shouldn't use in this case. Since `contains` will match for the class like `test table-row`, `test table-row test`, `test1 table-row`, ... soon.