# ImportXML on Google Sheets - how to get a user variable (kind of)?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

After managing to import the filmography for any actor on [rateyourmusic.com](https://rateyourmusic.com/films/cary_grant/) via

```
=importxml("https://rateyourmusic.com/films/cary_grant/","//li")
```

I couldn't figure out how to retrieve my own user rating for certain titles (which would also tell me which title in the list I've already seen).

As I'm still learning my ropes around the importxml command, all I found out is that they're under the **'film_cat_catalog_msg_1050'** Xpath identifier(?), but fiddling with said command, all I could get on a separate column on my spreadsheet, was the standard 'rate' word so far - but no personal rating.

Could anyone help me with that, please?

```
<li><span onclick="RYMartistPage.openFilmCataloger(1050);" class="disco_cat_inner"><span class="disco_cat_catalog_msg"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i> </span> <span id="film_cat_catalog_msg_1050">4.5</span></span><div id="film_cataloger_1050" class="film_cataloger"><div class="film_cataloger_close" onclick="RYMartistPage.collapseFilmCataloger(1050);"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> </div> <div id="film_cataloger_content_1050" class="film_cataloger_content"></div></div>
     <div class="has_tip film_rel_img delayed_discography_img" data-delayloadurl="url('//e.snmc.io/lk/m/l/45956edc922ce07e2b84a6ff23da3452/6152891.jpg')" data-delayloadurl2x="url('//e.snmc.io/lk/t/l/48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99/6152891.jpg')" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(&quot;//e.snmc.io/lk/t/l/48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99/6152891.jpg&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></div><div class="disco_avg_rating">3.81</div><div class="disco_ratings">1,063</div><div class="disco_reviews">25</div>     <div class="film_info">    
     <div class="film_mainline recommended">
        <a title="[Film1050]" href="/film/his_girl_friday/" class="film">His Girl Friday</a>
     </div>
     <div class="film_subline">
     <span title="18 January 1940 " class="disco_year_ymd">1940</span> • Walter Burns 
     </div>
     </div></li>
```

As you have to be logged in in order to see said ratings, here's a screenshot for those who aren't members:

[rateyourmusic.com filmography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SkYl.jpg)

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting to say: I'd probably need _'start-with'_ for the id's, just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644921/wildcard-usage-with-xpath) as the number following each entry (such as in 'film_cat_catalog_msg_**8409**') changes every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this XPath query:

```
//span[@id="film_cat_catalog_msg_1050"]
```

[**Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.openFilmCataloger(1050)%3B%22%20class%3D%22disco_cat_inner%22%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22disco_cat_catalog_msg%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-left%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22film_cat_catalog_msg_1050%22%3E4.5%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_1050%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_close%22%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.collapseFilmCataloger(1050)%3B%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-right%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_content_1050%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_content%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22has_tip%20film_rel_img%20delayed_discography_img%22%20data-delayloadurl%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Fm%2Fl%2F45956edc922ce07e2b84a6ff23da3452%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20data-delayloadurl2x%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20style%3D%22background%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200)%20url(%26quot%3B%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%26quot%3B)%20repeat%20scroll%200%25%200%25%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_avg_rating%22%3E3.81%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_ratings%22%3E1%2C063%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_reviews%22%3E25%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_info%22%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_mainline%20recommended%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20title%3D%22%5BFilm1050%5D%22%20href%3D%22%2Ffilm%2Fhis_girl_friday%2F%22%20class%3D%22film%22%3EHis%20Girl%20Friday%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_subline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20title%3D%2218%20January%201940%20%22%20class%3D%22disco_year_ymd%22%3E1940%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%A2%20Walter%20Burns%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fli%3E&=-&extract=%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22film_cat_catalog_msg_1050%22%5D&=%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22film_cat_catalog_msg_1050%22%5D&input-format=html&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

---

As you have already guessed, we need something like `starts-with` since the numeric part is acutally variable:

```
//span[starts-with(@id, "film_cat_catalog_msg_")]
```

[**Demo 2**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.openFilmCataloger(1050)%3B%22%20class%3D%22disco_cat_inner%22%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22disco_cat_catalog_msg%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-left%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22film_cat_catalog_msg_1050%22%3E4.5%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_1050%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_close%22%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.collapseFilmCataloger(1050)%3B%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-right%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_content_1050%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_content%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22has_tip%20film_rel_img%20delayed_discography_img%22%20data-delayloadurl%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Fm%2Fl%2F45956edc922ce07e2b84a6ff23da3452%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20data-delayloadurl2x%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20style%3D%22background%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200)%20url(%26quot%3B%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%26quot%3B)%20repeat%20scroll%200%25%200%25%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_avg_rating%22%3E3.81%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_ratings%22%3E1%2C063%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_reviews%22%3E25%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_info%22%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_mainline%20recommended%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20title%3D%22%5BFilm1050%5D%22%20href%3D%22%2Ffilm%2Fhis_girl_friday%2F%22%20class%3D%22film%22%3EHis%20Girl%20Friday%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_subline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20title%3D%2218%20January%201940%20%22%20class%3D%22disco_year_ymd%22%3E1940%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%82%C2%A2%20Walter%20Burns%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.openFilmCataloger(1058)%3B%22%20class%3D%22disco_cat_inner%22%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22disco_cat_catalog_msg%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-left%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22film_cat_catalog_msg_1058%22%3E3.5%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_1050%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_close%22%20onclick%3D%22RYMartistPage.collapseFilmCataloger(1050)%3B%22%3E%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-caret-right%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film_cataloger_content_1058%22%20class%3D%22film_cataloger_content%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22has_tip%20film_rel_img%20delayed_discography_img%22%20data-delayloadurl%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Fm%2Fl%2F45956edc922ce07e2b84a6ff23da3452%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20data-delayloadurl2x%3D%22url(%27%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%27)%22%20style%3D%22background%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200)%20url(%26quot%3B%2F%2Fe.snmc.io%2Flk%2Ft%2Fl%2F48b945e1a503ab7a9dce538a50fa9b99%2F6152891.jpg%26quot%3B)%20repeat%20scroll%200%25%200%25%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_avg_rating%22%3E2.81%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_ratings%22%3E1%2C063%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22disco_reviews%22%3E25%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_info%22%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_mainline%20recommended%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20title%3D%22%5BFilm1050%5D%22%20href%3D%22%2Ffilm%2Fhis_girl_friday%2F%22%20class%3D%22film%22%3EHis%20Girl%20Friday%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22film_subline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20title%3D%2218%20January%201940%20%22%20class%3D%22disco_year_ymd%22%3E1940%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%82%C2%A2%20Walter%20Burns%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fli%3E&=8&extract=%2F%2Fspan%5Bstarts-with(%40id%2C%20%22film_cat_catalog_msg_%22)%5D&=%2F%2Fspan%5Bstarts-with(%40id%2C%20%22film_cat_catalog_msg_%22)%5D&input-format=html&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

And putting it all together:

```
=importxml("https://rateyourmusic.com/films/cary_grant/","//span[starts-with(@id, 'film_cat_catalog_msg_')]")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried it before but it doesn't work, I'm afraid.